# .NET Core MongoDB. Find by guid returns null

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following setup:

The document:

```
    [BsonCollection("Users")] // I get the collection name with a custom extension
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class UserDocument
    {
        [BsonId]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public UserSettingsModel UserSettings { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserSettingsModel
    {
        // ...
    }
```

The repository:

```
public class UserRepository
    {
        private readonly IMongoCollection<UserDocument> _collection;
        private readonly ILogger<UserRepository> _logger;

        public UserRepository(IMongoDatabase database, ILogger<UserRepository> logger)
        {
            // returns "Users"
            var collectionName = typeof(UserDocument).GetCollectionName();
            _collection = database.GetCollection<UserDocument>(collectionName);
        }

        // ...
         
        public async Task<UserDocument> GetById(Guid id)
        {
            var filter = Builders<UserDocument>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, id);
            var user = await _collection.FindAsync(filter);

            // var user = await _collection.FindAsync(x => x.Id == id); - doesn't work either

            var request = filter.Render(
                _collection.DocumentSerializer,
                _collection.Settings.SerializerRegistry).ToString();
            _logger.LogDebug(request);
            return user.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

And I initialize the client this way:

```
// ...

BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));

var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var database = client.GetDatabase(dbName);

services.AddSingleton(c => database);

// convention pack and registries 
// ...

// if moved here doesn't work either
// BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));
```

The filter generated in `GetById` is still the following: `{ "_id" : CSUUID("459f165a-4a91-4f39-906c-dc7401ee2468") }` when I expect it to be `UUID` instead of `CSUUID`.

So, the query doesn't  find anything and returns null. In the database the document I'm searching for has `_id: UUID('459f165a-4a91-4f39-906c-dc7401ee2468')`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fixing by this trick:

```
var mongoConnectionUrl = new MongoUrl(connectionString);
var mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(mongoConnectionUrl);
// before initializing client
mongoClientSettings.GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard;
```

However setting the `GuidRepresentation` in client settings is obsolete, which is quite confusing. Also, the query generated still has `CSUUID` instead of `UUID`. I was able to log the query the following way:

```
mongoClientSettings.ClusterConfigurator = cb =>
{
    cb.Subscribe<CommandStartedEvent>(e => logger.LogDebug($"{e.CommandName} - {e.Command.ToJson()}"));
};
```

If anyone finds a better way and post it here it would be appreciated.

Comment: look at this https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/reference/bson/guidserialization/serializerchanges/guidserializerchanges/ (and related articles). In 2 words, you use an old way to work with guids (V2 GuidRepresentationMode) that is depricated for now. A new way is `V3 GuidRepresentationMode` (the GuidRepresentationMode itself is also depricated because it's going to be removed together with the whole V2 mode)